# Unable to test kaggle dataset with react native tensorflow

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, image-recognition, kaggle

I want to use Kaggle flower dataset (with `4242` images uploaded) for flower recognition app with react native tensorflow. 
However, currently, I am sticking on a stupid mistake.

I am unable to change `flowers.npz` and `label.npz` files after data preparation followed by kaggle official website(https://www.kaggle.com/jrmst102/flow-ers-data-preparation/notebook) into `tensorflow_graph.pb` and `tensorflow_label.txt` formats.

So questions are as follows :

1. How to transform `flowers.npz` and `labels.npz` files into `tensorflow_graph.pb` and `tensorflow_label.txt`  extensions respectively?
2. Or how to properly upload this pretrained flower dataset into react native application, for testing purposes with react native tensorflow?

Googling all over around did not help me. 
Any advice is appreciated!

P.S. In case, I am developing an app using `CRNA`

Comment: To answer your first question: I don't know about the react app, but .pb file refers to a protobuf. In this case, the serialized form of the tensorflow graph. There's no transforming `flowers.npz` or `label.npz`, since they are data files. I'm guessing they should be used as inputs to the graph? Some more details about the app and the overall objective would help.

Comment: Actually, I have found out, that I do not have to, necessarily, follow kaggle data preparation steps. It is better to follow 'Tensor flow for poets' (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#8). All instructions are given regarding the retraining and transfer learning step by step for specific flower dataset given in the kaggle as well. Good luck to everyone, if it was the point of stuck to you also.